# Adjust to column width and vertical text

Tags: tables, adjustwidth

I've tried several different solutions that I read here for the problem I'm having but none of them have worked. So I'm sorry if I'm repeating the question. So I have this code:

```
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Descrição das categorias operacionais e de design segundo a norma EN45545-1.}
\label{categorias}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{XXXXXX}
 &  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Categoria de design}} \\
 &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Veículos\\  standard\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Veículos\\ automáticos sem\\  staff treinado\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Veículos de\\  dois andares\end{tabular} & Carruagem-cama \\
\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Categoria Operacional}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Veículos de superfície que não atravessam túneis ou secções elevadas de terreno, com possibilidade de evacuação lateral\end{tabular} & HL1 & HL1 & HL1 & HL1 \\
 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Veículos que atravessam túneis/secções de terreno elevadas, com possibilidade de evacuação lateral e alcance de um local de segurança num curto espaço de tempo, em caso de acidente\end{tabular} & HL2 & HL2 & HL2 & HL2 \\
 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Veículos que atravessam túneis/secções de terreno elevadas, com possibilidade de evacuação lateral e alcance de um local de segurança num longo espaço de tempo, em caso de acidente\end{tabular} & HL2 & HL2 & HL2 & HL3 \\
 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Veículos que atravessam túneis/secções de terreno elevadas, sem possibilidade de evacuação lateral e alcance de um local de segurança num curto espaço de tempo, em caso de acidente\end{tabular} & HL3 & HL3 & HL3 & HL3
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

And it turns out like this:

[image]

I wish it to turn out something like this here below. Which would basically mean to adjust the text of the second column to a smaller one, and put the text on the first column vertically. Doesn't need the background colors.

Thank you so much to anyone for your help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code snippet isn't compilable. Please tell us which packages you load and how or where the `X` column type is defined.

Comment: The culprit is most probably your nested tabulars in the second column:  the column specifier `X` is changed to `c`, which is for single-line cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this solution, with only one `X` column – of course within a `tabularx` environment. I also loadd `geometry`, to have more decent margins (if you don't use marginal notes), replaced most nested tabulars with `\thead` from `makecell` (this allows for line breaks in standard column cells) and finally added some space between rows with the `booktab` command `\addlinespace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell, booktabs, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
\caption{Descrição das categorias operacionais e de design segundo a norma EN45545-1.}
\label{categorias}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cXcccc}%
 & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Categoria de design}} \\
 & & \thead{Veículos\\ standard} & \thead{Veículos\\ automáticos sem\\ staff treinado} & \thead{Veículos de\\ dois andares} & \thead{Carruagem-\\cama }\\
\multirow{19}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries Categoria Operacional}} %
& Veículos de superfície que não atravessam túneis ou secções elevadas de terreno, com possibilidade de evacuação lateral & HL1 & HL1 & HL1 & HL1 \\
\addlinespace
 & Veículos que atravessam túneis/secções de terreno elevadas, com possibilidade de evacuação lateral e alcance de um local de segurança num curto espaço de tempo, em caso de acidente & HL2 & HL2 & HL2 & HL2 \\
\addlinespace
 & Veículos que atravessam túneis/secções de terreno elevadas, com possibilidade de evacuação lateral e alcance de um local de segurança num longo espaço de tempo, em caso de acidente & HL2 & HL2 & HL2 & HL3 \\
\addlinespace
 & Veículos que atravessam túneis/secções de terreno elevadas, sem possibilidade de evacuação lateral e alcance de um local de segurança num curto espaço de tempo, em caso de acidente & HL3 & HL3 & HL3 & HL3
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I am really grateful to you!

Answer (score 2):

As you've (re-)discovered, using `\resizebox` to force a `tabular` environment into the width of the text block will hardly ever generate a satifactory solution. Hence, *do not* use `\resizebox` -- at least not for the purpose of resizing a table.

I will assume that the `X` column type in your code snippet is defined by the `tabularx` package. (If this assumption is wrong, do let me know!) The following solution uses a `tabularx` environment with unequal column widths. (Note that the relative column widths sum to `5`, which is equal to the number of columns of type `X`.) I've gotten rid of the `tabular` wrappers in the header row -- they're not needed since the `C` column type allows automatic line wrapping. I've also gotten rid of the first column. In my experience, readers *strongly dislike* having to crane their necks to read somethinng; I tucked the string "Categoria operacional" into the header row instead.

The following screenshot shows (roughly) the upper half of the table generated by the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional 

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
%% Define variable-width raggedright and centered versions of the "X" column type:
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%
        \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash%
        \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Descrição das categorias operacionais e de design segundo a norma EN45545-1.}
\label{tab:categorias}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L{2.2} C{0.6}C{0.9}C{0.7}C{0.6}  @{}}
\toprule
Categoria operacional & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Categoria de design} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& Veículos \emph{standard} & Veículos automáticos sem staff treinado & Veículos de dois andares & Carruagemcama \\
\midrule
Veículos de superfície que não atravessam túneis ou secções elevadas de terreno, com possibilidade de evacuação lateral & HL1 & HL1 & HL1 & HL1 \\
\addlinespace
Veículos que atravessam túneis\slash secções de terreno elevadas, com possibilidade de evacuação lateral e alcance de um local de segurança num curto espaço de tempo, em caso de acidente & HL2 & HL2 & HL2 & HL2 \\
\addlinespace
Veículos que atravessam túneis\slash secções de terreno elevadas, com possibilidade de evacuação lateral e alcance de um local de segurança num longo espaço de tempo, em caso de acidente & HL2 & HL2 & HL2 & HL3 \\
\addlinespace
Veículos que atravessam túneis\slash secções de terreno elevadas, sem possibilidade de evacuação lateral e alcance de um local de segurança num curto espaço de tempo, em caso de acidente & HL3 & HL3 & HL3 & HL3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I marked the other comment as the correct one solely because people who might have the same doubt as me of turning a text into vertical get the right response. Thank you once again!